# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=nx^n(1-x^n)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I want to check the uniform convergence of the sequence of function $f_n(x)=nx^n(1-x^n)$ on $[0,1]$.

My approach: We can see $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$

Now If we consider the sequence $x_k=(1/k)^\frac{1}{k}$ in $[0,1]$ then $f_n(x_n)=n\frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n})$ ,therefore $M_n=\sup|f_n(x)|>1$, which is nonzero, so it is not uniformly convergent.

Is this correct? Or is there any easy way to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: You can actually compute the maximum of $f_n$. Hint: It's at $x=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: You computed $f_n(x_n)$ incorrectly.

Comment: @Gary thank you for pointing out.  the actual sequence of function was $f_n=nx^n(1-x^n)$. Previously I had written it wrong.

Comment: @Stefan Lafon thank you for your comment. I made a correction on the sequence of function.

Comment: Note that if $n\geq 2$, then $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} \left| {f_n (x)} \right| \ge f_n (x_n ) = 1 - \frac{1}{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}.
$$ Thus, $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} \left| {f_n (x)} \right| \ge \frac{1}{2}.
$$ Your claim $M_n>1$ does not follow from your analysis and is not needed. Another good choice is $f_n (2^{ - 1/n} ) = \frac{n}{4}$. This shows how badly $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: @Gary ohh that's  right ! Thank you